# document.getElementsByName("") equivalent in YUI3.0

Tags: javascript, yui

AS we know that to get value of an element by ID in YUI3.0 we use below code.

```
Y.one("#element_id");
```

Is there any equivalent code in YUI 3.0 for document.getElementsByName("element_name"); of javascript.

Comment: Y.all('CSS_SELECTOR')

Answer (score 1):

You can use any CSS selector, such as the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var all_element_names = Y.all('[name="element_name"]');
```

Also, keep in mind, if the browser supports the native `getElementsByName()` method, YUI will use it. But if the browser does not support the native method, YUI will brute force the DOM to find the attribute, with a performance penalty.